# Self-intersection of exceptional sphere

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology, complex-geometry, symplectic-geometry

Let $M$ be a smooth close $4-$dimensional manifold and let $p\in M$ be a point. Denote by $\hat{M}$ the blow-up of $M$ at $p$ and let $E \cong \mathbb{C}P^{1}$ denote the exceptional sphere which is embedded. How can one show that the self-intersection number of $E$ is $-1$, i.e. $E \cdot E = -1$?

Comment: Do you know any reference where the answer of Ashwath Rabindranath from your link is explained in more detail? I have to admit that I am new in this field.

Comment: For general 4-manifolds, this is essentially by definition. The blowup replaces a ball with  a punctured $\overline{\Bbb CP^2}$. The exceptional sphere is just the sphere representing a line in $\Bbb CP^2$. There is no (as far as I know) other reasonable extension of the algebraic geometric definition.